# Value of HttpFileCollectionBase Isnull on Postback

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, httpfilecollection

I'm curious instead of using HTTPFileWrapper, i created a model with HttpFileCollectionBase type of property.

```
public class UserLoginModel
{
[Required]
[Display(Name = "User name")]
public string UserName { get; set; }

[Required]
[DataType(DataType.Password)]
[Display(Name = "password")]
public string Password { get; set; }


public HttpFileCollectionBase Resume { get; set; }
```

}

My View

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("", "User", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", @class = "form-horizontal" }))
{
   //  @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.LabelFor(x => x.UserName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.EditorFor(x => x.UserName)
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Password)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Password)
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <input type="submit" value="login" onclick="return Upload();">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Resume, new { type = "file" })
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
}
```

And my Controller for postback

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(UserLoginModel obj)
```

but when I checked the value of model.Resume on the controller the value was null. what could be the reason for that? thanks

Comment: It should be `public HttpPostedFileBase Resume { get; set; }`

Comment: @StephenMuecke Will you make your comment as an aswer. I would gladly accept it! thanks

Comment: @StephenMuecke done. i clicked up arrow last time sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You using the wrong class. Your property needs to be `HttpPostedFileBase`

```
public class UserLoginModel
{
    ....
    public HttpPostedFileBase Resume { get; set; }
}
```